# Nagios: check_memory plugin not showing critical and warning limits

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I am using check_memory plugin to check available memory on my machine. I have specified the warning and critical limits, but this plugin is not displaying it while other plugins like check_mem displays it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am new to cassandra and Icinga, Is there anything which I am missing.

Comment: Can you share with us your output of this plugin and output which you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for responding. In output I am getting the free, warning and critical memory but it is in bytes so the number size is bigger like: 123456789 and I think this may be cause that it is not showing in icinga dashboard. I tried to change the number size and making it in GB but no success as I am not much aware of python and I think the plugin is developed in python. Please suggest me the way I am stucked here though its a minor issue, when its not showing values in prod it could be major one. 

Output in console is : CHECK_MEMORY OK - 9G free | free=10457866240b;1603295232:;4008238080:

Comment: Can you share download link to this plugin?

Comment: https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_memory-2Esh/details

Comment: This plugin is writed in Bash, not Python. This plugin uses linux command `free -m` and parse that output. So, it is OS specific - different output on each OS/version. And this can be your problem.

Comment: Thanks for Info. I am not much familier with bash and python as well. I got the problem, I have edited the plugin file. Some conversions were not there and that was causing the issue. I fixed this at my end but I think plugin should be updated for people who are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot for displaying the warning and critical conditions for this plugin but it didnt worked. What I did is now I have updated plugin code. In code the : is appended at the end of warning and critical conditions I removed them and also removed the unit of measurement and it started displaying values in bytes.